# Detect which object conceals another one

Tags: algorithm

I've searched for a while for a good solution and if I'd have found one I wouldn't be here. So there are the details:
I have been working on my 2D game using XNA, and I'm aware of the way XNA renders objects(If "a" was drawn after "b", it will draw "a" above "b"). 
In the game I'm making there's a character that is able to move left, right, up and down.
I'm, using Rectangle's "Intersects" method, when the rectangle on the character is placed on his feet, to detect collision detection.
I would also like the character to be able to move behind a house(Just like you can in real life, and the house will hide a part of the character that is hidden behind the house).
So far, all the things that I've mentioned are accomplished. Now, I would like to hear how would you recommend detecting whether the character is standing in front of the house, and hiding the part of the house that his standing in front of, or whether the character is standing behind the house. I understand it might be a little hard to understand, therefore I added a picture that will simulate the situation. (No I'm not the one doing the drawing)
Any help, advices, or criticism would be appreciated. Thanks ahead!
[image]

Comment: isn't a z-sort of your elements the way to go ? (you'll have to think about intersection vs z, since character, when behind the house, intersects with the house but not the door).

Comment: I added a Z value and collision detections works the same,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily accomplished by giving each object a Z value, a single value that determines how far away from the screen it is, if you want to look determine what object is in front of the other you just look at which one has the smaller z value.

Comment: Just to make sure, before I do anything rash, If I was using only 2D Vectors, will I need to change them to 3D vectors? or is Z=0 the default state and I won't need to change any of the other 2D Vectors?

Comment: Well you can convert 2D vectors into 3D vectors that should work fine as long as your algorithms also work with 3D vectors (you can easily check that by changing it and seeing what breaks, just be sure to have a backup/versioning system in place). If don' t want to have to rework everything you can also add in another variable called z and give it to each object (less clean but also less likely to break existing code).

Comment: don't think of 'z' as indicating the 'depth' or something : just think of it as way of sorting your items. In a second time you might use the z to change the scale / project y for a quite nice effect. The math are a bit tough though.